# Detect whether or not the camera is in use?

Tags: actionscript-3, webcam

[The docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#getCamera()) say

> If getCamera() returns null, either the camera is in use by another
>   application, or there are no cameras installed on the system. To
>   determine whether any cameras are installed, use the names.length
>   property

So to detect that the camera is taken, I should be able to check  `if (Camera.getCamera() == null && Camera.names.length > 0)`, right?

I can duplicate having my webcam "taken" by another application by opening Webcam Toy in IE, and then trying to debug my application in Chrome, but `Camera.getCamera()` still returns a camera object, even when I can't see the feed from my webcam.

If I turn off the IE application and restart my app in Chrome, I can see the feed again.

Is the documentation wrong, or am I wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect in a Flex app if a camera is already in use by another application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546271/how-to-detect-in-a-flex-app-if-a-camera-is-already-in-use-by-another-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help. I wrote a blog post a while back about detecting multiple cameras and setting the default in AS3. Hopefully you find this information useful.

Blog post:
http://www.charlesclements.net/blog/flash-as3-setting-default-camera-part-2/

Source files:
http://www.charlesclements.net/blog/swfs/camera_detection/UseDefaultCameras_201203141746.zip